# How to free an unmanaged memory that was allocated by marshalling from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling

C++ code calls C# method which returns string. How I should free the allocated unmanaged memory in C++? Should I use free() or delete?

C#:

```
[Guid("52E4971F-E075-41BA-A84F-B6BE8BD66A21")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
[ComImport]
public interface ISomeInterface
{
     [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
     string SomeMethod([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string text);
}
```

C++:

```
class SomeClass
{
    virtual int32_t __stdcall _someMethod(const char16_t *text, char16_t **r) = 0;

    char16_t * someMethod(const char16_t *text)
        {
            char16_t * result;
            _someMethod(text, &result);
            return result; // how to correct release this memory?
        }
}
```

The solution works on Windows as well as on Linux.

Comment: Could you please show some / your code so we can help in the best way possible?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your calling an object that has a COM signature like this:

```
interface MyObj
{
   HRESULT __stdcall MethodOrProp([out, retval] BSTR* SomeStringReturned);
};
```

Then, you call SysFreeString.

```
MyObj* pObj;
// ....

BSTR bstr = NULL;
HRESULT hr = pObj->MethodOrProp(&bstr);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
   // ... do junk with string ...
   SysFreeString(bstr);
}
```

But, if you are using Visual Studio, then don't worry about it and use CComBSTR.  It will do the cleanup for you in its destructor.

```
CComBSTR ccbString = NULL;
HRESULT hr = pObj->MethodOrProp(&ccbString);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
   // ... do junk with string ...
}
// some time at end of scope, destructor of ccbString will clean it up
```

Comment: thank you for answer. I have added more details to my problem description. Could you look at it again?

Comment: And as I understand, I can't use BSTRs for non-windows systems. Am I correct?

Comment: Ummm.  yes.... Where are you going to use COM except on Windows?  I realize I am a Windows programmer and don't keep up on other platforms except on the periphery, but I don't know of any serious, applications grade implementations of COM except for Microsoft's on Windows...it's their technology.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson: COM specifies a standardized ABI. Anyone can implement a runtime infrastructure targeting that very same ABI. And with the Mono project (which I assume also supports the `ComVisible` attribute), non-Windows COM objects may even exist.